# Office.js getAttachmentsAsync fails in client

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I successfully call the getAttachmentsAsync function from office.js in the webbrowser, all attachments are returend, but in the client, the function returns "failed" and - sorry a german error message - "Dieser Vorgang wird nicht unterstützt" what means "This process is not supported".
I've implemented the call on base on this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form

```
var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
var options = { asynContext: { currentItem: item } };
item.getAttachmentsAsync(options, function (result) {
    console.log(result.error.message);
});
```

[image]

To reproduce the error:

1. create a web addin with the code above (for edit mode)
2. open new email, attach some files
3. and call the code

The call returns the following:

- code: 5000
- name: Hostfehler
- message: Dieser Vorgang wird nicht unterstützt

Comment: Could you share what client you're facing this issue on and the repro steps.

Comment: I have edit the question, please take a look there.

Comment: What format are the attachments? The list of supported formats can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.attachmentcontentformat?view=outlook-js-preview)
Also, in your snippet, make sure that "asynContext" is actually "asyncContext"

Comment: i used a .png file, renaming to "asyncContext" doesn't help. the error only occurs in the outlook client, in owa it works.

Comment: The getAttachmentsAsync API is supported in requirement set 1.8. You can verify the requirement set before calling the API by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets). Your Outlook build does not support this API, so you have to upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: Ok, but it's not mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form , it would be nice if there would be one point of documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, we will update our documents.